# Facing issue while fetching data with "&" special characters

Tags: java, xml, velocity

We have one **screen/page** in our application where we are showing different columns for different products. These all records in the columns are fetched from database.

Also, We have two **export** buttons at the bottom of the screen which is meant for showing all those records in the **PDF** and **XLS** format.

These functionalities are working fine except under one condition. We have one column **name** in the screen whose values are fetched from database. when any record under **name** column has **&** in it, the export functionality stopped working.

**For example** :-

for name "BOWOG BEHEER B.V.", the export is working fine for both pdf and xls.

But for the name "BOWOG & BEHEER B.V.", it stopped working. While clicking on **export** button, pdf and xls is showing as blank page.

Could anyone please help ?

Below is the piece of codes :- (not full code)

```
public class CVRExportServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");

    /** context. */
    private ResourceContext context = null;

    private Map createParametersFromRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        // copy all request parameters
        final Map parameters = new HashMap();
        final Enumeration names = request.getParameterNames();

        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            final String name = (String) names.nextElement();
            final String[] values = request.getParameterValues(name);

            if (values.length > 1) {
                parameters.put(name, values);
            } else {
                parameters.put(name, values[0]);
            }
        }
        // parse request uri to get type and format
        final String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        String type = StringUtils.left(requestURI, requestURI.lastIndexOf('.'));
        type = StringUtils.substring(type, requestURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        final String format = StringUtils.substring(requestURI, requestURI.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

        parameters.put(Constants.EXPORT_TYPE_PARAMETER, type);
        parameters.put(Constants.EXPORT_FORMAT_PARAMETER, format);

        // determine themeUrl
        final String requestUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        final int index = requestUrl.indexOf(request.getContextPath());
        String server = "";
        if (index > -1) {
            server = requestUrl.substring(0, index);
        }

    private void fillParameters(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Map parameters)
      throws ApplicationException {

        parameters.put("props", ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages"));

        // Create search request using the search form
        final SearchForm form = (SearchForm) request.getSession().getAttribute(
        (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(CvrConstants.SESS_ATTR_CVR_SEARCH_FORM_NAME));
        final SearchRequest searchRequest = form.getSearchRequest();
        searchRequest.setPageNumber(1);
        searchRequest.setRowsPerPage(10000);
        parameters.put("searchRequest", searchRequest);     
    }

    public void service(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // create parameters from request
        final Map parameters = this.createParametersFromRequest(request);
        parameters.put(ResourceContext.class.getName(), this.context);

        try {
            this.fillParameters(request, response, parameters);
            final SearchRequest searchRequest = (SearchRequest) parameters.get("searchRequest");
            if (searchRequest == null || searchRequest.getCounterPartyList() == null
                    || searchRequest.getCounterPartyList().isEmpty()) {
            throw new ExportException("Exception occurred while handling export: empty counterparty list");
            } else {
                if (searchRequest.getCounterPartyList().size() == 1) {
                    this.handleSingleReportExport(response, parameters);
                } else {
                    this.handleMutlipleReportExport(response, parameters);
                }
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            this.handleException(e, request, response);
          }
       }

    private void handleSingleReportExport(final HttpServletResponse response, final Map parameters) throws Exception {


        final XmlExportService exportService = this.getXmlExportService();
        final ApplicationContext context = this.getApplicationContext();
        final XmlTransformationService xmlTransformationService = (XmlTransformationService) context.getBean("transformationService");

        // perform export
        exportService.export(parameters);

        // perform transformation
        final ExportResult exportResult = xmlTransformationService.transform(parameters);

        // write result to stream
        response.setContentType(exportResult.getContentType());

        response.setContentLength(exportResult.getContentLength());
        if (parameters.get("format").equals("csv")) {

            response.setContentType("text/csv");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=export.csv");
        } else if (parameters.get("format").equals("pdf")) {

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=export.pdf");
        }

        final ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(exportResult.getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    }

    private void handleMutlipleReportExport(final HttpServletResponse response, final Map parameters) throws Exception {
        final SearchRequest searchRequest = (SearchRequest) parameters.get("searchRequest");

        response.setContentType("application/force-download");
        response.setHeader("Content-Encoding" , "x-compress");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=export_" + parameters.get("format") + ".zip");

        final XmlExportService exportService = this.getXmlExportService();
        final ApplicationContext context = this.getApplicationContext();
        final XmlTransformationService xmlTransformationService = (XmlTransformationService) context.getBean("transformationService");

        // start the zip process
        final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

        // create a file for each counterparty and add it to the zip file
        for (final String counterPartyId : searchRequest.getCounterPartyList()) {
            // make sure to reset the counterparty to the current one in the loop
            searchRequest.setCounterPartyList(Arrays.asList(new String[] {counterPartyId}));

            // perform export
            exportService.export(parameters);

            // perform transformation
            final ExportResult exportResult = xmlTransformationService.transform(parameters);

            // add the file to the zip
            final String fileName = counterPartyId + "_" + sdf.format(searchRequest.getRevaluationDate()) + "." + parameters.get("format");

            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
            zos.write(exportResult.getBytes());
            zos.closeEntry();
        }
        // finish the zip process
        zos.flush();
        zos.close();    
    }
```

---

I have some idea now. actually the issue is there at vm (velocity template). The "name" column is fetched from vm file and code is something like this :-

$!{result.counterpartyName}

This is in for each loop for multiple records. Could anyone please suggest how can i ignore special characters in the vm file itself. so that we will be able to export correctly even if "name" column has "&" or "-" etc special characters.

Comment: Can you share some code? It's impossible to help you with so little details.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Below are the piece of codes :-

Comment: could you please look into this now.

Comment: have you debugged to check at which line the code "stops working"? Please add that to the question as well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems based on your code that you are using an XML transformation service.

I'd say it's probably your data in your parameters containing dangling `&` sign. To be valid XML ready for transformation, `&` should be `&amp;`. However, based on the code given it is not possible to say where the XML data is coming from. You say it's coming from the database, so my *guess* is that the problem should be dealt with by modifying the data in the database.

Edit:

It seems I was partly right, but the database doesn't contain the XML - if I got this correctly, data is coming from database as raw tabular data, but is formatted to XML using velocity templates. If that's it, then XML escaping should be used in velocity template [like this](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html#xml%28%29).

Comment: I have some idea now. actually the issue is there at vm (velocity template). The "name" column is fetched from vm file and code is something like this :-                                            <cell align="left">$!{result.counterpartyName}</cell>                  This is in for each loop for multiple records. Could anyone please suggest how can i ignore special characters in the vm file itself. so that we will be able to export correctly even if "name" column has "&" or "-" etc special characters.

Comment: @user2326831 in the question you said that issue is with exporting to PDF and XLS. Are you using velocity templates to export to PDF? That seems hard to believe.

Comment: yes, we are using velocity template. that is what my client is using. could you please help me out ?

Comment: @user2326831 is the velocity template used by transformation service? can you show us the template used?

Comment: @user2326831 and shouldn't you use [velocity XML escaping](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html#xml%28%29)?